# Abbreviations: taking into account spacing AND punctuation

Tags: spacing, punctuation

So I'm trying to come up with some *good*, *general* definitions for latin abbreviations in my TeX template...

What I did up to now is this:

```
\usepackage{xspace}
\newcommand{\etc}{etc.\xspace}
```

..which works fine for **spacing**, but does not solve the problem of "blah etc.." at the end of a sentence when I use the macro like `blah \etc.`. So I had a look around and found the nice solution in this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3282319/correct-way-to-define-macros-etc-ie-in-latex), which I slightly modified to:

```
\usepackage{expl3}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\newcommand{\appendFullStop}[1]{
  \peek_meaning:NTF . {% Same as \@ifnextchar
    #1\@}%
  { \peek_catcode:NTF a {% Check whether next char has same catcode as \'a, i.e., is a letter
      #1.\@ }%
    {#1.\@}}}
\ExplSyntaxOff
% Omit final dot from each definition, it is added automatically when needed!
\newcommand{\etc}{\appendFullStop{etc}}
```

Now, *this* works fine for **punctuation**, meaning that `..blah \etc.` is actually compiled to "..blah etc." and not "etc..". BUT I now again have the spacing problem...

So I thought to solve this by merging the two approaches. But changing the last line in the above snippet to

```
\newcommand{\etc}{\appendFullStop{etc}\xspace}
```

breaks the punctuation thing again...

I am lost on this, any help would be really appreciated!

---

Example of the second code snippet not handling spacing:

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{xspace}

% Define a macro to look ahead one character and append a full-stop
\usepackage{expl3}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\newcommand{\appendFullStop}[1]{
  \peek_meaning:NTF . {% Same as \@ifnextchar
    #1\@}%
  { \peek_catcode:NTF a {% Check whether next char has same catcode as \'a, i.e., is a letter
      #1.\@ }%
    {#1.\@}}}
\ExplSyntaxOff
% Define the style for latin abbreviations
% Omit final dot from each definition, it is added automatically when needed!
\newcommand{\etc}{\appendFullStop{etc}}

\begin{document}
Test \etc in the middle. \\
After comma \etc, we test as well. \\
Finally at the end of a sentence \etc. \\
\end{document}
```

Comment: The code is meant to handle the spacing problem, through the "\@" it inserts: it treats "\etc. And" differently to "\etc and", because the "\@. " it inserts makes the space after the "." wider, in this sentence ending case, while the other occurrences of "\@" narrow the following space.  Could you post an example where this isn't working correctly?

Comment: See above. I'm talking about the first of the three test sentences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, in a attempt to find *the* solution, here a combination. I decided to use the `\xspace` package to avoid manually dealing with the whole spacing thing - in my experience `\xspace` is actually pretty good at that...

### Version 1

Suppresses the period at the end of a sentence if the next character is a `.`.

```
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{xspace}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\newcommand{\latinabbrev}[1]{
  \peek_meaning:NTF .
  {#1\xspace}
  {
    #1.\xspace
  }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\newcommand{\etc}{\latinabbrev{etc}}
```

### Version 2

Supresses the period if the next character is a `.`, `!` or `?`. I am not sure if this is typographically sound, at least I have no sources that go either way. If you're interested in a discussion, I posted a question on english.stackexchange [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/104066/etc-at-the-end-of-a-sentence-ending-with-or).

```
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{xspace}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\newcommand{\latinabbrev}[1]{
  \peek_meaning:NTF .
  {#1\xspace}
  {
    \peek_meaning:NTF !
    {#1\xspace}
    { 
      \peek_meaning:NTF ?
      {#1\xspace}
      { 
        #1.\xspace
      }
    }
  }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\newcommand{\etc}{\latinabbrev{etc}}
```

If you have any suggestions, please join the discussion...

Answer (score 1):

The following change to the macro seems to fix the problem (I added some text to your example to show off end-of-sentence punctuation):

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{xspace}

% Define a macro to look ahead one character and append a full-stop
\usepackage{expl3}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\newcommand{\appendFullStop}[1]{
  \peek_meaning:NTF . {% Same as \@ifnextchar
    #1\@}%
  { \peek_catcode:NTF a {% Check whether next char has same catcode as \'a, i.e., is a letter
      #1.\@\ }%
    {#1.\@}}}
\ExplSyntaxOff
% Define the style for latin abbreviations
% Omit final dot from each definition, it is added automatically when needed!
\newcommand{\etc}{\appendFullStop{etc}}

\begin{document}
Test \etc in the middle. \\
After comma \etc, we test as well. \\
Finally at the end of a sentence \etc. Two. Three. \\
\end{document}
```

The space following the second case (for the abbreviation being followed by a letter) was being gobbled, which does not happen with `\` - I think this is an expl3 syntax thing, since spaces are usually not signifianct then; I'm surprised I did not notice this before when I tested it.

This is very much a hack.  For instance, it does not handle sentence-ending punctuation other than `.` correctly.  Until someone implements The Right Thing, beware when using this sort of macro.  Also, it seems overkill to load the expl3 macros for such a tiny thing as testing catcodes, but no doubt this will seem quite natural a few years from now.

Name of macro: I prefer `\latinabbrev`, since it gestures at the particular functionality we want; the name alone suggests the quite different `\def\appendFullStop#1{#1\@.}` is good implementation.

Comment: Concerning the macro name: guess you are right, I just used 'latinabbrev' to also include some styling (I like using \emph{...} or \textsl{...} for latin abbreviations). :)